# Create a empty JSON object from an existing JSON object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, angularjs

I have a JSON object with two arrays of an object `x`.

I'm using angularJS and I want to add/edit/delete objects in the JSON (just like the Angular TODO app example on angular.org).

Is there a way to create a new empty (with the structure of `x` but no values) JSON object of `x`, and simply push that to the above JSON object array?

How do I go about creating an empty value JSON object of `x`?

My Sample object x is (I nullified all the values) pasted below. So my JSON is just an array of these objects. In Angular, I want the user to fill out a form and hold the data in an empty object of this type and push it to the array. That's my goal.

**Sample JSON**

```
      [{
        "id": null,
        "title": "",
        "date": {},
        "billPayerId": null,
        "notes": "Sample Notes",
        "billFinances": {
            "billPayerId": null,
            "billItemEntry": [
                {
                    "itemDescriptionId": 1,
                    "itemDescription": "",
                    "userIdAndLiableCost": [
                        {
                            "userId": null,
                            "liableCost": null
                        },
                        {
                            "userId": null,
                            "liableCost": null
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "itemDescriptionId": null,
                    "itemDescription": "",
                    "userIdAndLiableCost": [
                        {
                            "userId": null,
                            "liableCost": null
                        },
                        {
                            "userId": null,
                            "liableCost": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "billTotal": null
        },
        "groupId": null
    }];
```

Comment: *You keep using that word "json object". I do not think it means what you think it means.* :D

Comment: I think I did not use the right terminology but what I meant was I have a JSON var holding an array of type object x. Hope it makes sense now...

Comment: you could always create a "template" json object and reuse it when you push it into the array.

Comment: @user1324816: Are you talking about serialized data structures, or actual JavaScript data structures? I really can't tell from your question. An empty "JSON object" would look like `""` in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry. I'll just post my json object. Otherwise, I'm just confusing everyone. Hate it when someone does the same to me.

Comment: If you want actual text-based JSON data, and you only want the structure, then there needs to be values, even if they're all `null`. If you want JavaScript objects, then you could use a constructor function that sets things up for you.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Thank you. Was thinking along the same lines. So I just created a new JSON with the same structure but with values as null (I edited my question and added the empty structure).

Comment: @user1324816: What to do sort of depends on how you're going to use this. Do you really need JSON? Typically when you're in JavaScript, you just work with Objects and Arrays, and then when you need to transfer them to a server, you serialize it as JSON. So I'm not sure I entirely understand your situation.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I think I've begun development in reverse. I wrote the Backend services to push my Java Object as JSON to the front end. Now I'm just trying to edit/delete/add to that JSON. Any drawbacks with what I have done? thanks.

Comment: JSON is **J** ava **S** cript **O** bject **N** otation - its way of representing data. So technically, you ARE dealing with JavaScript Objects and in your case, an array :) Finally. Damn you SO editor."P

Comment: @user1324816: Well, when it's JSON, it's a string, so there's no handy way to edit it in its JSON form. But when you parse the JSON into JavaScript, it becomes more usable. So if you're saying that you've sent a "uninitialized" JSON structure from the server to the client, then you could take that structure, parse it into JavaScript structures, and then populate it as needed. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Perhaps there's a better approach. JavaScript isn't strongly-typed (you can add/change/remove object properties on a whim), so a placeholder-type object with a bunch of null values isn't required or generally useful...

Comment: @user113215 You maybe right. I'm just trying to create an array of form submissions, collect it and then send the array back to the server. So I just wanted to create an object var that can hold the form submission but I thought wouldn't it be nice if I'm able to generate the structure of the new var with that of the objects I have in the array..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an object literal to store whatever you want.  It is just a bag of properties (i.e. name) and values.  e.g. `var order = {};`

Then an array literal could be used to hold the orders.  `e.g var orders = []; orders.push(order);`  But it would be just as easy to use another object literal with the id as a property.

But it seems like you want some sort of validation.  Perhaps something to manage the order data and handle the validation, etc.  Like so:

```
orderManager.dataStore = {
  _data: {},
  //_redundantData = [];  //could easily store in an array if id isn't unique
  get: function (id) {
    return this._data[id];
  },
  getAll: function () {
    return this._data;
  },
  set: function (id, order) {
    validateOrder(order);
    this._data[id] = order;
  },

  clear: function (id) {
    this._data[id] = undefined;
  },
  add: function (order) {
      validateOrder(order);
      this._data[order.id] = order;

  },
  assertNotNull: function (data, key) {
      if(data[key] == undefined) {
        throw new Error("Key Missing: " + key + " for " + data.name);
      }
  },
  validateOrder: function(order) {
    assertNotNull(order,"id");
    assertNotNull(order,"title");
    //etc
  },
  containsOrder: function (id) {
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        if(array[i].id === id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading all of this right, I think you may be misunderstanding how Angular works. You don't have to create an empty object for Angular to use within a form. As long as your form's inputs use dot notation, it will generate the object for you as the user fills in the inputs with data.

E.g.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.email">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.nickname">
</form>
```

Since we used the dot notation in the `ng-model` attribute, it creates the object for us as the user fills out the form. The generated object would look like this after the inputs are completed:

```
$scope.myForm = {
    name: 'Justin',
    email: 'justin@email.com',
    nickname: 'Cerebrl'
};
```

Now, normally once the user clicks save, you'd send the data to the server for persistence and you could then just empty the object (e.g. `$scope.myForm = {};`) to reset the form. But, for some reason, you want to build an array first, then send the whole thing to the server when fully complete (at least that's how I'm understanding it).

To do this, you have to get around the fact that `Objects` and `Arrays` in JavaScript are reference types, so you can't push the object full of data to an array, and then empty the object to reset the form as that would then empty the object within the array as well, blowing your data store.

I would personally address this problem with Angular's object copy method (e.g. `angular.copy(source);`) seen here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy This allows you to make a non-referenced copy of an object and use it without mutating the original object. So, within the "save function", you would have this:

```
var myNewObj = angular.copy($scope.myForm);
myDataArray.push(myNewObj);
$scope.myForm = {};
```

That way, you've saved the completed form data, pushed it to the array and cleared the form's input data. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you. That is definitely helpful!